# Can I use a .cc proto file in client side and .java proto file in server side

Tags: java, c++

I'm new one to protobuf

I have searched  and learned some things about protobuf and I know that using protobuf package we are able to generate the classes in c++ ,java and python for proto files and even I learnt something about third party library for RPC implementation

Now my doubt is, suppose if I want to  implement a client and server program where in client side I'll use a some proto file and I'll generate c++ classes for that proto file and in server side i wish to use the same proto file and their i will generate java classes for that proto file

is it possible to use like this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is one of the main purposes of Protocol Buffers.  Compile the .proto file to C++ and Java.  You'll have to use some kind of transport supported by both languages.  But a protocol buffer serialized in C++ will deserialize just fine in Java.

Comment: Thank you for  reply japreiss, and even i have one more doubt actually i did one client and server program in c program using a proto file and there i didnt use protoc instead i used protoc-c so i got .h and .c files once i compiled the proto fole using the protobuf-c compiler and now i have to change server side program to c++ so there can i use c++ version proto file and if used is it possible...?

Comment: Why don't you just recompile with `protoc --cpp_out` to get C++ code?

Comment: yes i can , but what i'm not getting is in client side ill use c version proto so according that it ll call server side sevices through rpc  now if i use c++ version proto in server is possible for client to communicate with server....?

Comment: through protoc i know that we can use java for client and c++ for server or some other combination but i'm not getting is same thing holds good even for protoc-c......?

Comment: Yes, it will work.  `protoc-c` wouldn't be very useful if it couldn't communicate with other Protocol Buffers implementations.

Comment: thank you japreiss can please give some information regarding rpc in proto files.....

Comment: ask another question if you need to.

Comment: japreiss can you please a give some information with example for an rpc implementation for c client and c++ server